# X cannot be added because it is already mapped to the entities. X entity class and the entity is not in current project source

Tags: java, entity-framework, netbeans, glassfish

I'm creating a new NetBeans EE Enterprise Application, and when I try to create Entity classes from database (Customer from the sample database), I can't select it because of this error :

[image]

Any idea? I'm using NetBeans 7.3 with Glassfish 3.1.2.

Comment: Any update to this problem? I am facing the same issue as well also.

Answer (score 19):

I found the answer after spending the last few hours searching in Google.
Delete the cache folder in the following

C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache

It solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case of NetBeans for Linux the answer of @Lawrence Wong applies too; but the cache folder is located in
`~/.cache/netbeans`
(at least in Fedora).

In my case, the problem was probably caused by assigning an Entity Class from a database in a test project that no longer exists.