# <entity> cannot be added because it is already mapped to the <package> entity class and the entity is not in current project source

Tags: netbeans, jdbc, glassfish, database-connection, connection-pooling

I think there might be a problem with the cache in Netbeans, which is causing a problem in creating a new `Entity Classes from Database...`.

Netbeans error:

```
clients cannot be added because it is already mapped to the net.bounceme.dur.jpa.Client entity class and the entity is not in current project source.
```

[image: cannot be added]

Note that this is using the resource `jdbc/ejb`.

the `persistence.xml` generated by the IDE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="A-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/ejb</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and the related `glassfish-resources.xml`, also generated by the IDE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_legacy_jdbcPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="legacy"/>
        <property name="User" value="jdbc"/>
        <property name="Password" value="password"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/legacy?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/ejb" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_legacy_jdbcPool"/>
</resources>
```

A different resource, on the [glassfish server, might not be directly related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534320/jdbc-connection-pool-details-on-glassfish):

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$ /home/thufir/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin
Use "exit" to exit and "help" for online help.
asadmin> 
asadmin> list-jdbc-connection-pools
CLI031: Warning: Option "target" is obsolete and will be ignored.
CLI031: Warning: Option "target" is obsolete and will be ignored.
__TimerPool
DerbyPool
SamplePool
connectionPool
legacy_on_glassfish
Command list-jdbc-connection-pools executed successfully.
asadmin> 
asadmin> ping-connection-pool legacy_on_glassfish
Command ping-connection-pool executed successfully.
asadmin> 
asadmin> list-jdbc-resources
jdbc/sample
jdbc/__TimerPool
jdbc/__default
jdbc/local
jdbc/legacy_resource
Command list-jdbc-resources executed successfully.
asadmin> 
asadmin> exit
Command multimode executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects$
```

although I think those resources on the glassfish server are [unrelated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295478/creating-entity-classes-from-database-using-glassfish-jdbc-resource), but there might be some interplay.

I've looked in:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ls /home/thufir/.netbeans
8.0.1
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ls /home/thufir/netbeans-8.0.1/
apisupport    etc      java                      nb            README.html            websvccommon
bin           extide   javafx                    netbeans.css  THIRDPARTYLICENSE.txt
CREDITS.html  harness  LICENSE.txt               platform      uninstall.sh
enterprise    ide      moduleCluster.properties  profiler      webcommon
thufir@dur:~$
```

see also:

[X cannot be added because it is already mapped to the entities. X entity class and the entity is not in current project source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207398/x-cannot-be-added-because-it-is-already-mapped-to-the-entities-x-entity-class-a)

http://pietervogelaar.nl/ubuntu-11-04-netbeans-7-clear-cache

perhaps I'm just not seeing the cache, assuming that's the problem?

Comment: might be here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17238597/262852   but I don't know whether that will actually fix the problem.

Comment: I deleted `.cache/netbeans/8.0.1` as per https://netbeans.org/projects/www/lists/nbj2ee/archive/2014-10/message/22   although I don't understand what the underlying problem was.  This enabled creating a entity class from the database connection.